# How do you show that $\textsf f(e_1) \wedge \textsf f(e_2) I^{-1} = \det (\textsf f) \bar{\textsf f}^{-1} (e_3)$ in geometric algebra in 3D?

Tags: clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

I would like to show that
$\textsf f(e_1) \wedge \textsf f(e_2) I^{-1} = \det (\textsf f) \bar{\textsf f}^{-1} (e_3)$

in geometric algebra in 3 dimensions, as in Geometric Algebra for Physicists (Doran & Lasenby) pg. 222.

Attempt (focusing on the wedge product factor at first):

\begin{align*}
\textsf f(e_1) \wedge \textsf f(e_2)
&= \textsf f(e_1) \wedge \textsf f(e_2) \wedge e_3^2 \\
&= \textsf f(e_1) \wedge \textsf f(e_2) \wedge (\textsf f^{-1} \textsf f (e_3) \cdot e_3) \\
&= \textsf f(e_1) \wedge \textsf f(e_2) \wedge (\textsf f (e_3) \cdot \bar{\textsf f}^{-1}(e_3)) \\
&= \textsf f(e_1) \wedge \textsf f(e_2) \wedge (\textsf f (e_3) \bar{\textsf f}^{-1}(e_3) 
- \textsf f (e_3) \wedge \bar{\textsf f}^{-1}(e_3) ) \\
&= \textsf f(e_1) \wedge \textsf f(e_2) \wedge (\textsf f (e_3) \bar{\textsf f}^{-1}(e_3)) - I \wedge \bar{\textsf f}^{-1}(e_3)  \det \textsf f \\
&= \textsf f(e_1) \wedge \textsf f(e_2) \wedge (\textsf f (e_3) \bar{\textsf f}^{-1}(e_3))
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\newcommand\lcontr{\mathbin\rfloor}
\newcommand\adj\bar
\newcommand\l\mathsf
$Doran & Lasenby's equations (4.4.2) are the key. Another way to state them is
$$
  \l f(\adj{\l f}(X)\lcontr Y) = X\lcontr\l f(Y).
$$
Now recalling that $XJ = X\lcontr J$ for any pseudoscalar $J$, apply $\adj{\l f}^{-1}$ to the equation
$$
  e_3 = e_1\wedge e_2\,I^{-1}.
$$